# Where are the sources for mingw stdc++ library?

Tags: mingw

A mingw deb package comes with a libstdc++-6.dll, but I can't find sources for it. A mingw-w64-v11.0.1.zip from sourceforge doesn't contain sources for stdc++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are part of GCC when built using MinGW-w64 as standard library.

For GCC sources see: https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/

I see calls to Windows functions like `_wopen()` in https://fossies.org/linux/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/filesystem/ops-common.h

Comment: There are parts that are very system dependent like filesystem namespace, and I do not see any windows related code in GCC sources

Comment: It's the combination of MinGW-w64 + GCC (or alternatively LLVM).

Comment: I need to find a windows implementation of filesystem namespace. Where is it? It is not a part of GCC and I do not see it in MinGW sources published on sourceforge

Comment: I updated my answer above, does this answer your question?